# Problem creating a project in CodenameOne with Netbeans 12.6

Tags: netbeans, codenameone, netbeans-platform

I have followed the instructions in the manual at https://start.codenameone.com/ to create a project. I found the following paragraph as important:

"Before opening the project in NetBeans, you need to copy the contents of the tools/netbeans directory into the root project directory. These files are required by NetBeans to build, run, and debug the project correctly. "

But I can't find this folder in netbeans version 12.6
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of [start.codenameone.com](https://start.codenameone.com) generate a netbeans version of the project by default if you pick it from the combobox on the side. So this step isn't needed.

Notice that this refers to the zip you downloaded from the site and expanded. The file listing you show seems to be from the netbeans installation directory.